# How to store nested Array-Object into Mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb

I've got struggled in storing data in MongoDB Atlas. the Array I wanted to store is like this:

```
Array [
  Array [
    "6352546fb6e1702a96df5931",
    "[{\"date\":\"2022-10-21\"},{\"index\":\"6352546fb6e1702a96df5931\"},{\"setDetails\":[{\"setIndex\":0,\"result\":12,\"weight\":\"12\",\"reps\":0}]},{\"setDetails\":[{\"setIndex\":1,\"result\":25,\"weight\":\"25\",\"reps\":0}]}]",
  ],
  Array [
    "6360db542adb98c1ac717890",
    null,
  ],
  Array [
    "636284882f3e1d9e6808071d",
    "[]",
  ],
  Array [
    "63628afd2f3e1d9e6808071f",
    null,
  ],
  Array [
    "63628b8d2f3e1d9e68080721",
    null,
  ],
  Array [
    "63628bf32f3e1d9e68080723",
    null,
  ],
  Array [
    "63628c092f3e1d9e68080725",
    null,
  ],
  Array [
    "63628cb72f3e1d9e68080727",
    null,
  ],
]
```

I tried various Schema types like array or object,

```
const UserWorkoutHistory = {
  workout: Object, // something wrong with this line
  userId: String,
};

const UserWorkoutScheme = mongoose.model(
  'UserWorkoutHistory',
  UserWorkoutHistory
);

module.exports = UserWorkoutScheme;
```

but although I got the same data on my backend correctly, nothing was stored on the DB. Could you please give a clue to find the solution?

**Update:**

I got data from AsyncStorage React Native:

```
const GetData = async () => {
    try {
      workoutId.map((item) => {
        //console.log('item', item);
        return AsyncStorage.getItem(item).then((value) => {
          //setData(value);

          const dataArray = JSON.parse(value);
          if (dataArray.length !== 0) {
            // console.log('value', data.length);
            setData((data) => [...data, dataArray]);
          }
        });
      });
    } catch (e) {
      alert(e.message);
    }
  };
```

then, simply send it by Axios post to the server :

```
const SyncData = () => {
    Axios
      .post('http://10.4.1.6:8080/userworkoutdata', {
        data,
        userId,
      })
      .then((res) => {
        //console.log('res', res.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('error', error);
      });
  };
```

this is what I get in post route on Express js

```
    630749ebb3c79314cc86877c //userId
[
      { date: '2022-10-21' },
      { index: '6352546fb6e1702a96df5931' },
      { setDetails: [ [Object] ] },
      { setDetails: [ [Object] ] }
    ] // data I wanted to store
```

user Id is stored correctly, but the data not

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why what you have is not working for you, I have a similar and it's working for me. But you can try

```
const UserWorkoutHistory = {
  workout: [[mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed]], // array of array of mixed
  userId: String,
};
```

Or

```
const UserWorkoutHistory = {
  workout: {type: Object},
  userId: String,
};
```

Comment: thank you, but after applying your snippet code, I got the same result,
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6363de8206a8458cee84e812"
  },
  "workout": [],
  "userId": "630749ebb3c79314cc86877c",
  "__v": 0
}
an empty array was stored

Comment: Can you share a code snippet of how you store the data?

Comment: I've updated my question with more data